# How can I find an element looping through a list of divs using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

In an HTML file structured like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="id">
        ID: 123456
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        Title 1
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        Description 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="id">
        ID: 89123
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        Title 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's say that I have a variable number of divs with the class "card", using Selenium I would like to loop through these divs and if there is div with the class description, I would like to print his text. 
I tried to do something like code below, but using `find_element_by_xpath`. I will always get the first element that has the class "description". How can I fix this and properly-getting elements by looping through divs? Thanks a lot.

```
cards = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='main-div']")

for card in cards:
    try:
        description = card.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='description']")
        print(description.text)
    except:
        print("No description")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all divs with class "card" and search the div "description" inside them:

```
cards = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card")

for card in cards:

    try:

        description = card.find_element_by_css_selector(".description")
        print(description.text)

    except:

        print("No description.")
```

PS: Or change your first XPath to `//div[@class='card']` and second XPath to `.//div[@class='description']` as proposed guys from another answers.

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.` for `intermediate` child tag.So it should be like that

```
card.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='description']")
```

**Code here:**

```
cards = webdriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='card']")

for card in cards:
    try:
        description = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='description']")
        print(description.text)
    except:
        print("No description")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one locator and a single loop.

```
for description in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card > div.description"):
    print(description.text)
```

NOTE: If you want a fix for your current code, you are just missing the self `.` axis in your second XPath. Change `"//div[@class='description']"` to `".//div[@class='description']"` to indicate that you want to start searching at the current `card` element.

For more info on the `self` axis, see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) which has a lot of great XPath and CSS selector related info.